# Logical error while running scanf in for loop, how do i fix it?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, structure, scanf

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct card
{
   char Top;
   char Bottom;
};

int main()
    {
    int T,i;
    struct card cards[4];
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            scanf("%c%c%c", &cards[0].Top, &cards[1].Top, &cards[2].Top);
            printf("%c%c%c\n", cards[0].Top, cards[1].Top, cards[2].Top);
        }
return 0;
}
```

It does not correctly print the three characters, outside the for loop it scans and prints fine.

Comment: "does not correctly print" is not a good description. What does it print? What do you want it to print?

Comment: Short summary of the duplicate: ```%c``` reads the whitespace (a line-break in particular) which concludes the numerical input. Use ```scanf(" %c%c%c", ...);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to your problem**

Change the `scanf` line to this. (Note the spaces before `%c`)

```
scanf(" %c %c %c", &cards[0].Top, &cards[1].Top, &cards[2].Top);
```

**Other comments on your code**

ALWAYS check return value from `scanf`. It should look like this:

```
if(scanf(" %c %c %c", &cards[0].Top, &cards[1].Top, &cards[2].Top) != 3) {
     // Print error message and exit program or something else
} else {
```

Comment: Besides feeding on a dupe, for the current shape of the post one space is enough in the front (```" %c%c%c"```)

Comment: @tevemadar If it is enough or not depends. The post does not say so explicitly, but this is better if the user presses enter after each character.

Comment: @tevemadar And maybe I should not have posted this answer, but I did not find a good duplicate for reading multiple chars.